SSH connection autentication says ok, but still fails to connect
enter image description here
as showed in the image above the connection works but permissions say denied but i double checked the permissions on the linux server to 600 and 644 using chmod command on the ssh key,when i manually check the connection on the server says ok, i even cloned the project using the ssh key so should be fine, my idea was to make a pull in the server each time this repository receives a pull request to main branch.
already explained all above

Please don't take a screenshot of text. Copy and paste instead.
